# FFmpeg use without closing process

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Is there a way to use `ffmpeg` in such a way that, it expects new data everytime it finishes it operation. For example, calling `ffmpeg` with a pipe, using a program, feed `ffmpeg` new frames while reading results, so keeping the process alive until desired time.

**Expected run:**

> Run command -> write frame to stdin -> read result(stdout) -> write
>   frame -> read result-> ...

I am using Python3 to pipe `ffmpeg`, if it helps.

Comment: ffmpeg can receive raw frames from stdin FWIW...

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes, it can recieve, but can it recieve continuously ? (generating results accordingly

Comment: Does each incoming frame have to be timestamped with the current wall clock, or is it stable?

Comment: @rogerdpack You can say that I am directly reading from camera, and encode the frames in chunks real-time, but I have to reopen a ffmpeg process to the same job over and over which increases the delay, I am trying to find if there is a better solution.

Comment: It can read from "stdin" for raw format types, that's about all I know, this may help: https://superuser.com/questions/685022/how-can-i-pipe-data-losslessly-to-and-from-ffmpeg GL!